# Search directories for multi line string

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files, diff

Looking for a way to recursively search a repository for all files containing a multi line string and return the file names that contain it. The paragraph is just a header approx 30 lines.
So I know `pcregrep` can do multi-line search. But you need to put the whole expression in. As this is a long paragraph I'm searching for, I want to place it in variable and just do a grep of that variable. So basically it would be `find . -name "*.[ch]" | xargs pcregrep -M $paragraph` But this does not work could anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: At a minimum, you should probably be quoting your search pattern `"$paragraph"`

Comment: youre searching `.[ch]`? use [`ctags`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ctags.html)

Comment: @steeldriver The pattern is 30 lines long though.

Comment: The searching of 30-lines string is useless. Try to choice some keywords from it to seek for.

Comment: @Gooner1990 I previously posted an answer and immediately deleted it as soon as I noticed that you were looking to match a 30 lines multi-line string; I changed my answer radically and undeleted it, it should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're trying to match the first 30 lines of your files you could save the text in a file e.g. `ref_file` then use `diff` to compare the reference file with the first 30 lines in each file:

```
find . -name "*.[ch]" -exec ./myscript {} \; -print
```

where `./myscript` is

```
#!/bin/sh

head -n 30 "$1" | diff - /path/to/ref_file >/dev/null
```

so `-print` in the first command is only executed if the previous `-exec` evaluated *true*, that is if there was no difference between the reference file and the first 30 lines from the current file.
Or, if you prefer without a script and saving the file names in a `logfile`:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'head -n 30 "$0" | diff - /path/to/ref_file >/dev/null' {} \; -print >logfile
```

Note that this assumes you're looking for an exact match otherwise `diff` exits with `1`, even if the difference was a single space.

Comment: Works great thank you very much. Instead of printing, I want to log to a file. I did this but does not seem to work `find . -name "*.[ch]" -exec ./myscript {} \; >>output.txt`

Comment: I want to log the filenames

Answer (score 2):

You could find each file to be processed using `find` and feed each filename to a script made on purpose to look for a match and print the filename in case of a match; I'd suggest to use a script rather than a one-liner for the added easiness of handling the multi-line string compared to the prompt.

That is:

```
find . -name "*.[ch]" -exec /path/to/script {} \;
```

Where `script` is this Perl script:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

$/ = ""; # sets the input record separator to an empty string
$_ = <>; # stores the content of the file specified in the first argument in $_

$string = <<EOF; # The multi-line string to match starts here
My
multiline
string
EOF
# The multi-line string to match ends here

/\Q$string\E/ && print($ARGV."\n"); # If $_ matches $string, prints the name of the file
```

- `$/ = "";`: sets Perl's input record separator to an empty string; this has the effect of making Perl read the whole file specified in the first argument to the script at once;
- `$_ = <>;`: stores the content of the file specified in the first argument in `$_`;
- `$string = <<EOF;` [...] `EOF`: stores the content of [...] in `$string`(replace [...] with the multi-line string to match);
- `/\Q$string\E/ && print($ARGV."\n");`: if `$_` matches `$string`, prints the name of the file.

This is the sample output on a test directory hierarchy made on purpose:

```
% for f in *; do printf '%s:\n\n' "$f"; <<<'' cat "$f" -; done
file1:

My
multiline
string

file2:

My
multiline
string

file3:

My
other
multiline
string

script.pl:

#! /usr/bin/perl

$/ = "";
$_ = <>;

$string = <<EOF;
My
multiline
string
EOF

$string = quotemeta($string);

/$string/&&print($ARGV."\n");

% find . -type f -exec ./script.pl {} \;                      
./file2
./file1
```

Comment: So I have perl script written and I `find . -name "*.[ch]" -exec search.pl` but I get I get an error returned `find: missing argument to `-exec'`

Comment: @Gooner1990 My bad, this is the right command: `find . -name "*.[ch]" -exec /path/to/script {} \;`